# How to replace element in a 1D list with zero comparing another list?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists namely `A` and `B`

```
A=[1,2,3,4,2,5,6,4,8,9]
```

Where `B`-list is the index of `A[]` elements that I should have

```
B=[0,3,5,7,8]
```

I need to replace the `A` list elements with zero which is not listed in `B`-list (index of `A`)

What I tried is :

```
Z=[0 if A.index(x) not in B else x for x in A]
```

but it returned

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I need is:

```
[1,0,0,4,0,2,0,6,4]
```

Comment: Your expected output is wrong for the condition you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.index` returns the first index a particular value is found. `enumerate` will come in handy here:

```
Z = [0 if i not in B else x for i, x in enumerate(A)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in `range(n)` where `n` is the length of first list, then check if the number is in `B`, if yes, then take `A[i]` else take `0`:

```py
>>> [A[i] if i in B else 0 for i in range(len(A))]
[1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 4, 8, 0]  #your expected output is wrong
```